# laravel artisan command Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have this issue when running any `artisan` commands on laravel application in Ubuntu server.

```
In MySqlProcessor.php line 16:
Undefined property: stdClass::$column_name
```

This issue is very recent and sudden and had no such issue before.

What could cause this issue and how do I fix this?

Comment: Check the __construct() method for every Command class. One of those is throwing the error.

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

The variable on line 16 in your `MySqlProcessor` is trying to access a `column_name` property but it doesn't exist.

I'm not sure what your code looks like but my guess is it's something like this:

```
$result->row->column_name
```

Perhaps an upgrade to Laravel or a PHP setting has changed it's strictness and before when this `column_name` didn't exist then PHP would just ignore it.

You'll need to update your code to have a guard statement:

```
if(isset($result->row->column_name)){
  ...then do your work
}
```

Comment: I haven't explicitly added any such code. Also, when I switch to other older branches, it is still the same.

Comment: Sorry, really can't help without knowing what that code looks like. If you can share in your original comment the content of the code we might be able to help further.